# Illegal characters in path exception

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I trying to get page from this url:
[YandexMarket](http://m.market.yandex.ru/guru.xml?CMD=-RR=9,0,0,0-VIS=160-CAT_ID=160043-EXC=1-PG=10-GRID=200&hid=91491)

but WebClient and httpWebRequest throw exception

```
Illegal characters in path.
```

HttpUtility.UrlEncode doesnt work for this symbol "-".

Firefox and other browser are correctly open the page.

Here is my code:

```
public string GetPage(string url)
{
    var wReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    return new StreamReader(wReq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

How i can get the page?

Sorry guys. All ok.

Comment: If you found a solution, please add it as an answer, and accept that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash is not an character that needs escaping in urls. Are you sure it's dash or not other character that looks like it?

Take care that the browser does not display the actual url that is using but a "user friendly" form of it.

See http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm